# EC2 instance DNS resolving issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli

How do I identify the EC2 instance causing DNS (my website) resolving errors?
I have some instances in my VPC, one of them is creating an error, I did not enable monitoring for this VPC and the instances.

I need to determine what instance of aws is resolving (mysite.com)?

my website (mysite) resolves to an ec2 instance but is erring

Can you suggest a way to find a solution?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Can you please try to clarify, and also all examples or relevant logs to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: i'm reviving 403 ERROR (cloudfront) The request could not be satisfied. Bad request. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error.

Comment: Are you saying that some of your requests work ok, but occasionally you get this error? Please edit your question to make it obvious what the problem is.

Comment: No actually , its not working at all yes some of the pages earlier return white screen , and 403 ERROR The request could not be satisfied. Bad request. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error.cloudfront (CloudFront) Request ID: to3QjS9nkb5NDT9BQpAE1LYCz5QAMYUnQvrp_sJTSaxQNCPxoFYVqLw== –

Comment: Is there any way to find that faulty EC2 instances which receive that cloud front and Route53 request.

Comment: Maybe load balancer logs, maybe CloudFront logs. You've really not made it easy to help you here, your description of the current state and the problem are imprecise and incomplete.

Comment: In my observation seems the issue is with nginx being port 80, and trying to proxy pass to 443 errors out. CloudFront needs 443 requests. Redirect to 443 works, and that may be the solution for now, but i need to identify  EC2 instance causing DNS (my website) resolving errors .

Comment: Logs are the only any to that. CloudFront, Load Balancer, VPC Flow Logs, or web server logs. You haven't told us enough about your environment for us to know.